# Computed Property on Dynamic Prop Object

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component that passes an object to a child, and that child has a computed property that is reliant on the object prop.

I can see that as I update the prop object in the parent that the prop is updated within the child but the computed property is only computed once upon loading and then never re-computes, same goes for watchers even if I use 'deep', the computed property or watched object never gets triggered.

Here is a code example (assume `orderData` is just some object)

orderData
`{'test': 5}`

Parent

```
OrderForm(
  :orderData='orderData'
)
```

Child

```
  computed: {
    orderJson() {
      console.log('computed')
      return JSON.stringify(this.orderData)
    }
  },
  props: ['orderData']
```

I have also tried

```
  watch: {
    orderData: {
      handler(val, oldval) {
        console.log('hanlded')
        this.orderJson = JSON.stringify(val)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

in both cases I see no updates to `orderJson` in my vue inspector, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using `orderJson` in the template? It only updates computed when you use it somewhere

Comment: Also your second attempt won't work. It _is_ possible to assign a value to computed props, but only if you declare them as such: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: Sorry yes I did not include the full code, but the computed property IS used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging out `this.orderJson` in your `orderData` watcher:

```
  watch: {
    orderData: {
      handler(val, oldval) {
        console.log(this.orderJson);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

Computed props aren't updated until they are used somewhere

**EDIT**: Here's a simplified example that I *think* does what you want, though I'm not 100% clear: https://codepen.io/codingcampbell/pen/219e1377e764659c16ebb8cefbca9ce9

Comment: The computed prop `orderJson` is used within the template like `v-model='orderJson'`, the element is an input

Comment: Try logging it .. a `v-model` wouldn't work for the same reason you can't set a value to a computed without declaring it like so: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: So can I use a computed property or do I have to use a watcher?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Start with `:value="orderJson"` instead of `v-model`

Comment: I tried that and had the same issue :(, sorry for not being clear. I am trying to set the value of a particular hidden input to be the JSONified version of the passed in prop

Comment: See my edit for a codepen example to see if that helps?

Comment: Yea you pretty much nailed it, I just made one too: https://jsfiddle.net/rh8qoytk/4/ but as you can see mine doesn't work. I feel like I am missing something dumb...

Comment: You're passing `order_data` but trying to compute with `this.orderData` .. they have to be the same name. See https://jsfiddle.net/yfb0rdsx/

Comment: Ok, this works, but what if I am adding new keys to the object etc.? For some reason I cannot get my computed property to update after the component loads, I have buttons that dynamically modify it but the computed property is always `{}` which is what I set it to initially in the parent

Comment: I see the issue, when I change the object from the parent's end the child does not detect the change in the object and hence the computed property is not run

Comment: Would you mind doing a quick online chat session with me?

Comment: Review these rules when you have a chance: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats - basically, new keys can't be detected, so make sure they are there at init, or use `Vue.set`

Comment: Basically the problem was that I was adding new keys and needed to use `Vue.set` to update/add them instead of conventional key addition.